# spring mongodb aggregation compare two field and get sum of one column

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a order collection and orderLastStatusChangeDatetime, estimatedDeliveryDatetime and orderPrice are filed name of orders collection. I have to get sum of  orderPrice  where orderLastStatusChangeDatetime less or equal to  estimatedDeliveryDatetime . I have used the below query to get the total record ...

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria() {
        @Override
        public DBObject getCriteriaObject() {
            DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
            obj.put("$where", "this.orderLastStatusChangeDatetime <= this.estimatedDeliveryDatetime");
            return obj;
        }
    };

    Query query = new Query();


    query.addCriteria(criteria);


    totalOrder = (int) mongoTemplate.count(query,ORDERS_COLLECTION_NAME);
```

But I have to get the sum of order price.  I have use the same criteria in aggregation match . But it give error "Command failed with error 16395: 'exception: $where is not allowed inside of a $match aggregation expression'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation pipeline. Creates a `cmp` field in `$project` stage to hold the result for `orderLastStatusChangeDatetime <= estimatedDeliveryDatetime` followed by `$match` with `cmp` equal to `true` and `$group` with `$sum` the `order price`.

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(project("orderPrice").andExpression("orderLastStatusChangeDatetime <= estimatedDeliveryDatetime").as("cmp"), match(Criteria.where("cmp").is(true)), group().sum("orderPrice").as("total"));

BasicDBObject results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, ORDERS_COLLECTION_NAME, BasicDBObject.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
int totalOrder = results.getInt("total");
```

Update: Use `AggregationExpression` in 1.8.5 RELEASE

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("orderPrice").and(new AggregationExpression() {
                @Override
                public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                    return new BasicDBObject("$lte", Arrays.<Object>asList("$orderLastStatusChangeDatetime", "$estimatedDeliveryDatetime"));
                    }
    }).as("cmp"),
    match(Criteria.where("cmp").is(true)),
    group().sum("orderPrice").as("total")
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help Veeram...But I am getting error ---

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Element: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.spel.OperatorNode@542dba3f Type: class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.spel.OperatorNode You probably have a syntax error in your SpEL expression!

Comment: You are welcome. I was able to run this successfully on 1.10.1 spring mongo version. Can you show me the code and what version are you using ? This is the query I see on the server `{ "$project" : { "orderPrice" : 1 , "cmp" : { "$lte" : [ "$orderLastStatusChangeDatetime" , "$estimatedDeliveryDatetime"]}}} , { "$match" : { "cmp" : true}} , { "$group" : { "_id" :  null  , "total" : { "$sum" : "$orderPrice"}}}`

Comment: Query I am using Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
     project("orderPrice","orderLastStatusChangeDatetime","estimatedDeliveryDatetime").andExpression("orderLastStatusChangeDatetime <= estimatedDeliveryDatetime").as("cmp"),
     match(Criteria.where("cmp").is(true)),    
     group() 
    .sum("orderPrice").as("total")    
    );

Comment: Okay I see your problem. The `lt` operator is not supported in expression. in 1.8.0 version. Can you upgrade to 1.8.5 RELEASE ? I've added solution for 1.8.5 RELEASE

Comment: Please use the other query from answer for 1.8.5 version. For the current query to work you'll need to update to 1.10.1 Release.

Comment: Thanks veeram.. I have updated the version to  1.8.5 RELEASE  and used your above mention code . Now  it is working fine .

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of example how to use it here:
https://www.javatips.net/api/spring-data-mongodb-master/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ProjectionOperationUnitTests.java